# Applying a function over multiple df that are NOT combined in a list

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, apply

I am aware of apply/map to run functions over a list of data frames but my problem is that the function uses the name of the data frame to create col names and this doesn't work using it on a list of dfs. Is there a way how I could automate running the function on several DFs without combining them in a list?

Alternatively I could probably also change the function so it gets the names from list objects but so far I failed with this as well.

Maybe someone has a solution?
Thanks a lot!

Example data

```
p.vals <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.0001)
logFCs <- seq(from=0, to=4, by=.1)
diffEx_proteins <- data.frame(protein=LETTERS[1:1000],
                      adj.P.Val=sample(p.vals, size=1000, replace=TRUE),
                      logFC=sample(logFCs, size=1000, replace=TRUE))

diffEx_proteins_2 <- data.frame(protein=LETTERS[1:1000],
                      adj.P.Val=sample(p.vals, size=1000, replace=TRUE),
                      logFC=sample(logFCs, size=1000, replace=TRUE))

list <- list(group1 = diffEx_proteins, group2 = diffEx_proteins_2)
```

Function

```
mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1 <- function(comparison){
dat <- comparison
name <- deparse(substitute(comparison))
dat[,paste(name,"up_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC >= 1
dat[,paste(name,"down_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC <= -1
dat[,paste(name,"up_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & dat$logFC >= 1
dat[,paste(name,"down_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & dat$logFC <= -1
dat[,paste(name,"reg_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & abs(dat$logFC) >= 1
dat[,paste(name,"reg_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & abs(dat$logFC) >= 1
return(dat)
}
```

map(list, mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1) results in cols with names starting with [[1]] but instead I would like to have the df name in it.

Thank you!
Sebastian

Comment: I you use `dplyr::lst()` you'll get a list of tables with items named as the tables themselves, then you can change your function, is this a possibility ? else you'll have to loop on the table names and use something like `eval(bquote(mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1(.(as.symbol(tbl_name)))))` but I hope you can avoid that

Comment: also I suggest you to avoid naming a list as `list` as it is quite confusing to have lists and functions named the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `imap` which passes the list as well as names of it

```
mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1 <- function(comparison, name){
    dat <- comparison
    dat[,paste(name,"up_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC >= 1
    dat[,paste(name,"down_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC <= -1
    dat[,paste(name,"up_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & dat$logFC >= 1
    dat[,paste(name,"down_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & dat$logFC <= -1
    dat[,paste(name,"reg_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & abs(dat$logFC) >= 1
    dat[,paste(name,"reg_0.001", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & abs(dat$logFC) >= 1
   return(dat)
}


purrr::imap(list, mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1)
```

`imap` is same as `map2` passed with names of list

```
purrr::map2(list, names(list), mark_significants_p.05and.001_fc1)
```

Comment: My understanding was that OP wanted the objects named "diffEx_proteins" etc, not "group1" etc, but I might have not understood properly

Comment: Cool, this actually solved it! Using the names of the list for naming is a sweet little workaround :)